# Google places autocomplete doesn't work properly

Tags: flutter, google-places-api

Is daily limit really only 1 request or am I missing something?  Sometimes I get suggestions but they disappear, on google console metrics I have 97% of 403 error. I use default following code:

```
Future<Null> displayPrediction(Prediction p) async {
    const kGoogleApiKey = "";
    GoogleMapsPlaces _places = GoogleMapsPlaces(apiKey: kGoogleApiKey);

    if (p != null) {
      PlacesDetailsResponse detail =
          await _places.getDetailsByPlaceId(p.placeId);


      var address = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromQuery(p.description);

      // print(lat);
      // print(address);
    }
  }

Prediction p = await PlacesAutocomplete.show(
                          context: context, apiKey: kGoogleApiKey);
                      displayPrediction(p);
```

Comment: Have you enabled billing on your project? If not, this is likely why you have a quota limit of 1 request per day. Also please make sure the Places API is enabled.

Comment: I don't, I thought I have at least few more without billing.

Comment: Enabling billing is mandatory to be able to use the Maps APIs. Please check out Google's documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started